# Calculating time based on velocity, distance and radius of two balls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, physics, game-physics

How would I get the time needed for two balls to collide when the following are all constants

initial position of both balls

initial velocity of both balls

radius of the both balls

I am doing out a few examples in Unity 3D using c# for the code. I am not asking for the code, I just would like to know what steps to take to do this (physics wise).

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 3):

Assume constants for each ball are distance (d1), velocity (v1), radius (r1), start position (p1)... etc. Also assume that the balls move in a 1D world along a tape measure.

distance = velocity * time

Distance between the balls accounting for their size:
distance = p1 - p2 - (r1 + r2)

Velocity is the combined velocities of the balls (V):
V = v1+v2
** note that direction matters. If they are going towards one another, they sum. Away from one another, they subtract.

So now...
V * t = p1 - p2 - (r1 + r2)

time to collision is:
t = [p1 - p2 - (r1 + r2)] / V